# сравнение текста по минимальному совпадению Java

Tags: java

Есть массив объектов. Нужно при получение текста вывести нужные элементы. Но, equals, находит только полное совпадение, а мне нужно частичное. Например, в массиве будет объект "Автомобиль Лада", этот объект нужно вывести при вводе слова Автомобили или Лада, а не только при вводе такого же.

Comment: Есть методы contains(), он вытянет совпадение хоть по одной букве, есть startsWith(), вытянет при совпадении начала строки, например: вводят Ла, вытянет все, что начинается на Ла.

Comment: Регулярку простейшую написать

Comment: @Charismatic можете оставить свой комментарий как ответ, он помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод `contains()`, он вытянет совпадение хоть по одной букве. Есть `startsWith()`, он вытянет при совпадении начала строки, например: вводят "Ла", вытянет все, что начинается на "Ла".

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы оно игнорировало регистр?

Comment: Приведи две строки к одному регистру s.toLowerCase().contains(s1.toLowerCase())